# expo-font not loading in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using expo-font for importing two fonts from outside. I used require function to import them. I also imported expo-font and `AppLoading` from expo. But i am getting an error saying `fontFamily "open-sans-bold" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.`

I have attached my app.js file here I used fontfamily in a different component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import GameOver from "./screens/GameOver";
import GameScreen from "./screens/GameScreen";
import StartGameScreen from "./screens/StartGameScreen";

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    "open-sans": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
    "open-sans-bold": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"),
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();
  const [guessRounds, setGuessRounds] = useState(0);
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!dataLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }
  const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
  };

  const gameOverHandler = (numOfRounds) => {
    setGuessRounds(numOfRounds);
  };

  const startNewGameHandler = () => {
    setUserNumber("");
    setGuessRounds("");
  };

  let content = <StartGameScreen onStartGame={startGameHandler} />;

  if (userNumber && guessRounds <= 0) {
    content = (
      <GameScreen userChoice={userNumber} onGameOver={gameOverHandler} />
    );
  } else if (guessRounds > 0) {
    content = (
      <GameOver
        onOutput={userNumber}
        numOfGuesses={guessRounds}
        onNewGame={startNewGameHandler}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header title={"Guess a number"} />
      {content}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Can anyone tell me possible ways to resolve them.
I deleted entire node-modules and again installed npm.
I also changed the import names from `expo` to `expo-font`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Remove `expo-font` from `package.json`
2. Remove `node_modules` folder, and maybe `package-lock.json` as well
3. Run `expo install expo-font`
4. Run `npm install`

Your project should load the font now.

Comment: The key is to install from `npx expo...` or `expo...` and not directly from a package manager (e.g. `npm install...`) - see https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/#usefonts.  It should just be needed to `npm uninstall expo-font` (or equivalent in whatever package manager is being used).  Then `npx expo install expo-font` (or `expo install expo-font` if installed globally.  Removing all `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` seems overkill imo