# Expo App is stuck on splashscreen in Testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I'm having an issue:
I built my app using expo eas, first time the app crashed, so I found that I need to wait for the font to load, so I've changed my app entry like this:

```
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Lato_100Thin,
    Lato_100Thin_Italic,
    Lato_300Light,
    Lato_300Light_Italic,
    Lato_400Regular,
    Lato_400Regular_Italic,
    Lato_700Bold,
    Lato_700Bold_Italic,
    Lato_900Black,
    Lato_900Black_Italic,
    Mermaid: require("./assets/fonts/Mermaid1001.ttf"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {

    async function prepare() {
      try {
        if (fontsLoaded) {
          await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
          setAppIsReady(true);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      }
    }
    prepare();

    
  }, [fontsLoaded])
```

But now my app works well in expo go but inTestflight is stuck on splashcreen...

Comment: I found that useFonts in expo go became true, in Testflight stay false, so:
- or the hooks are not working in Testflight
- or the fonts are not working  in Testflight

Comment: I tried to do as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094348/11368483

Still no luck, still stuck on splash screen